# Долгие вычисления в вебе

Tags: очередь, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, асинхронность

Мне очень понравились ответы на мой предыдущий вопрос, поэтому я снова к вам.

Предположим, для каждого пользователя, который обратился к определенному урлу, у меня начинаются вычисления, которые могут длиться порядка 10-ти секунд (или больше). Тут же появляется вопрос, что делать, чтобы пользователь этих 10 секунд не видел пустую страницу.
Я вычитал много интересной информации, которую пока не до конца структурировал, поэтому вижу следующие пути решения:

- Использовать очереди сообщений и синхронный бэкенд сервер. В этом случае сервер создает сокет соединение с клиентом и отдает ему html страницу (стили, скрипты и все остальное в этом духе отдает nginx), а в очередь отдает задачу на вычисления и после получения ответа от очереди пушит клиенту результат.
- Использовать асинхронный веб-сервер (python tornado, node.js). Знаю, что tornado создает экземпляр класса для каждого клиента и при этом в цикле не забывает о других пользователях. Поэтому, как я понимаю, можно отдать пользователю html, настроив сокет соединение, и прямо в классе вьюхи вызвать функцию вычислений и пушить клиенту результат.
- Наверное, никто не станет бить меня по рукам и губам, если я подумаю об использовании асинхронного сервера и очереди, но сам я пока  не вижу с этого выгоды.

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем преимущества каждого из способов, какие варианты еще есть и правильно ли я вообще себе все представляю. Понимаю, что объяснять это все долго, поэтому буду благодарен и если просто закидаете меня кучей ссылок :)

Comment: > Предположим, для каждого пользователя, который обратился к определенному урлу, у меня начинаются вычисления которые могут длиться порядка 10-ти секунд (или больше). Тут же появляется вопрос, что делать, чтобы пользователь этих 10 секунд не видел пустую страницу.

Хотелось бы знать более подробно, что Вы там делаете. Чтобы можно было давать конкретные советы. Ну а пока у меня к Вам встречный вопрос, почему на данный URL не обращаться через AJAX, а во время выполнения запроса просто выводить пользователю картинку (gif), что идет загрузка?

Comment: @sp7, хотелось бы узнать про популярные и универсальные способы решения вопроса, независимо от того, что конкретно происходит (думаю, практически все можно свести к вызову одной функции). Можно обращаться и через ajax, но при этом вопрос об архитектуре сервера остается открытым.

Comment: Вообще "синхронный сервер", "асинхронный сервер" -- никто такие термины не использует, и вообще непонятно, что точно здесь имелось в виду.

Comment: Можете ли вы ещё до начала выполнения задачи мгновенно спрогнозировать, как много времени займёт её выполнение?

Comment: @Sergiks, нет, не могу, но с ответом определился. Всем спасибо за обсуждение и помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поучаствую в олимпиаде.

В чем разница между "поставил задание в очередь" и "отдал ответ клиенту, но продолжил обработку"? В том, что второй случай абсолютно беззащитен перед прорвой клиентов. Когда есть очереди, есть и фиксированное количество обработчиков, и нагрузку можно как-то контролировать (хотя если обработчики кривые, они все равно смогут повесить сервер), в то время как асинхронный подход не будет смотреть на загрузку сервера и пытаться выполнить работу в любом случае, что легко может создать сотни процессов/потоков на сервере и просто убьет все к чертям. Этого можно избежать, если отслеживать количество выполняемых сейчас задач и ждать, пока количество выполняемых задач не упадет до приемлемого... то есть реализовать половину функционала очередей какого-нибудь gearman. Причем наверняка без синхронизации, т.е. несколько задач смогут разом увидеть свободное место и разом включиться.

Безусловно, если приложение использует один человек в минуту, то на это наплевать. Но смысла не использовать очереди я не вижу, особенно учитывая, насколько легко перенести воркеров на другой сервер, разгрузив тем самым основной.

Comment: Вопрос ТС, как мне показалось, больше про UX, нежели backend.

>> приемл**е**мого

Comment: Меня интересовало, именно как обрабатывать все это дело со стороны backend, и благодаря этому ответу я понял, в чем преимущество очереди перед асинхронным сервером в моем случае. Спасибо.

Comment: @Sergiks спасибо, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: ну вот, - хэдшот. холивар окончен.  
ТС-ру рекомендую в дальнейшем задавать вопросы с конкретикой, дабы не плодить холивары и кармодрочерство в ответах. Мы все здесь люди-человеки, и у нас дохренищща недостатков на фоне собственной гениальности.

Answer (score 2):

Решение этой проблемы одно единственное. Два варианта указанных вами -- на самом деле одно и то же.

Вам необходимо обработать запрос, отправить задачу в очередь и ответить клиенту страницей.

А вот каким именно образом пользователь будет получать результаты выполнения это асинхронной задачи -- тут уже есть разные варианты:

- Делать запросы на сервер с определённым интервалом, проверять выполнена задача или нет. Если да, то забрать результат, если нет, то повторить запрос через N.
- Long polling. Браузер делает запрос на сервер, который очень долго обрабатывается, на самом деле тупо спит, ждёт результатов выполнения.
- Websockets. Браузер устанавливает соединение с сервером, ждёт сообщений от сервера.

Первый вариант самый простой и тупой, его можно сделать даже на убогом PHP. Вторые два варианта позволяют снизить количество запросов на сервер, однако требуют чтобы процесс обрабатывающий запрос жил долго. У многих платформ (кроме Erlang/OTP разумеется) проблемы с этим -- течёт память. Не могу сказать что лучше Node.js или Tornado -- не работал с ними.

Кроме того, наверное было бы круто, если бы можно было бы прикрутить websockets интерфейс к очереди сообщений (RabbitMQ?). Тогда можно было бы просто выставить этот интерфейс во внешний мир, браузер бы смог узнать что его задача выполнена вообще не трогая ваш бэкенд.

Резюме: чтобы быстро и просто -- запрос с интервалом (первый вариант). Более грамотно и эффективно -- websockets.

Comment: Любому здравомыслящему разработчику очевидно, что в мире программирования не бывает "одного единственного" решения проблемы. Нежелание искать и принимать альтернативы -- как минимум непрофессионально.

Comment: @deivan да у тебя баттхёрт, товарищ. "любому очевидно", "непрофессионально" -- это всё фигня. Может раскроешь свою позицию, в чём я не прав?

Comment: вступительный минусосрач 2015 года

проплюсовал на всякий обоих

Comment: и long polling, конечно, нет там никакого пула

Comment: @Etki, да, спасибо

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev эй, моряк, ты слишком долго плавал?.. Лет 8 назад я бы с тобой полностью согласился, что обработчики очередей - наше всьо. Ибо на тот момент полноценную асинхронность давали только серверные монстры, развернутые на джава, асп.нет и т.д. Но сейчас, слава Всевышнему, есть более удобные и высокоэффективные инструменты, внедрение которых стоит значительно меньше, чем разворачивание на сервере томката и дженкинса. И поддержка вебсокетов для того  же экспресса - нативна, и не требует дополнительных телодвижений, в отличие от пхп-реализаций.

Comment: @deivan даже если код не выглядит как очередь, он устроен и ведёт себя именно так. Приведите пример инструмента, который бы делал то что просит автор, и при этом это была бы не очередь.

Answer (score 0):

Считаю целесообразным использование Node.js:
во-первых, это самостоятельный полноценный инструмент серверного асинхронного программирования
во-вторых, скрипт на ноде прекрасно будет уживаться с тем же PHP, что даст возможность состряпать сайт и UI хоть на вордпрессе/джумле/друпале, и при этом корректно подключить нодовский скрипт как сервис, не нагружая обработкой основной сайт

Comment: Тогда нам нужно будет использовать очереди для общения php и node.js, если я все правильно понял. В чем тогда преимущество асинхронного node.js перед тем же php скриптом, вынесенным как отдельный сервис?

Comment: @zesudageg на мой взгляд, Ваш вопрос слишком абстрактен, сузьте его до конкретной технологии. P.S. Данная задача может решаться по-разному, в зависимости от веб технологии и используемого сервера.

Comment: @sp7, так я задавая этот вопрос и хотел узнать какие технологии и принципы построения эффективны в каких случаях.

Comment: Ну а, собственно, случай я вроде бы описал: есть html страница и данные для нее. Только данные эти вычисляются очень долго. Как лучше их отдавать и что для этого использовать? Перед тем как задавать вопрос, погуглил и изложил свои соображения в основном вопросе.

Comment: @zesudageg, да в принципе любая современная технология это может сделать. Например, если Вы будите использовать ASP.NET MVC то длительный вычисления можно будет положить в асинхронный экшен, для того чтобы разгрузить пул потоков сервера. Затем обратиться через ajax к этому экшену. Возвращать данные можно в том формате, который Вам удомен в конкретной ситуации. Например, json, xml или html.

Comment: ок, ПРИМЕР: он-лайн игрушка, у которой авторизация/мыло/процесс-квесты/форум выполнены на пхп/мускл, а то, что требует интерактивности - чат и бои он-лайн, вынесены были на ноду и редис. Как результат - 300 онлайн юзеров и 3000 хостов в сутки, и все работало безотказно. До этого пытались интерактивность эмулировать очередями в пхп - все валилось.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, вам следует взглянуть на свой же вопрос с другой стороны. Проблема в долгих вычислениях, а подобные проблемы не решаются только выбором технологий веб серверов (уверен, серебряной пули здесь нет). Возможно, вам стоить подумать о том, как уменьшить указанное время за счёт:

1. Оптимизации вычислений.
2. Кэширования результатов вычислений.
3. Рассмотрения вопроса железа.
4. Возможно, предложений было бы больше, если бы вы подробней описали эти самые вычисления.

В вопросе пустой страницы и ожиданий пользователя я солидарен с предложением [[@sp7](/users/16781/sp7)](/users/16781/sp7):

> обращаться через AJAX, а во время выполнения запроса просто выводить пользователю картинку (gif), что идет загрузка

Comment: Ни один из четырёх пунктов не поможет, просто неправильный путь. Что если эти вычисления -- перекодировка видео? Тут хоть заоптимизируйся, никак не выполнить задачу за время меньше секунды.

Comment: Именно по этой причине автору вопроса стоило бы подробнее описать проблему. Что касается вашего кейса о перекодировке видео, то одним из очевидных решений я вижу выполнение данных действий отдельным процессом(или несколькими, если необходимо) без ожидания запросов пользователя. Это решение условно можно отнести к кешированию, о котором я писал выше

Comment: Vladimir Gordeev, хотелось бы узнать подробности, почему вы считаете, что это неправильный путь? Я прочел ваш ответ и, насколько я понял, вы предлагаете лишь пути как клиенту асинхронно забрать данные с сервера (на мой взгляд, предложенные вами решения слишком тяжеловесны для данного кейса. Они не ускорят получение пользователем запрашиваемых им результатов вычислений, но добавят лишних стрессов с их реализацией, особенно если человек ранее подобного не делал).

Comment: > Это решение условно можно отнести к кешированию, о котором я писал выше

Нельзя. Это разные вещи.